# Сортировка даты в ключе

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста. Я понимаю тут нужна функция

```
[14/12/2019] => 17
[17/12/2019] => 37
[15/12/2019] => 21
[16/12/2019] => 37
[18/12/2019] => 39
[19/12/2019] => 23
```

Нужно отсортировать по дате. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array("14/12/2019" => 17,
"17/12/2019" => 37,
"15/12/2019" => 21,
"16/11/2019" => 37,
"19/12/2019" => 39,
"18/12/2018" => 23
              );
function date_sort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$a)) - strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$b));
}
uksort($array, "date_sort");
print_r($array);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет [uksort](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_uksort.asp):

```
    $array = array("14/12/2019" => 17,
"17/12/2019" => 37,
"15/01/2019" => 21,
"16/04/2019" => 37,
"19/12/2019" => 39,
"18/12/2019" => 23
              );
function order_date($a1,$b1) {
    $format = 'd/m/Y';
    $a = strtotime(date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $a1), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $b = strtotime(date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $b1), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    return $a<=>$b;
}

uksort($array,"order_date");
print_r($array);
```

Вывод

```
Array
(
    [15/01/2019] => 21
    [16/04/2019] => 37
    [14/12/2019] => 17
    [17/12/2019] => 37
    [18/12/2019] => 23
    [19/12/2019] => 39
)
```

Comment: я пробовал этот вариант, но он не берет во внимание месяц

Answer (score 1):

Предложу еще следующее:

```
$array = [
    '14/12/2019' => 17,
    '17/12/2019' => 37,
    '15/12/2019' => 21,
    '16/11/2019' => 37,
    '19/12/2019' => 39,
    '18/12/2018' => 23
];

uksort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $a) >= date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $b);
});

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/8v7mb